# Difference between 2 expression, one with spread and another without spread?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Using this object for an example

```
 ingredients = {
     salad: 3,
     bacon: 1,
     cheese: 1,
     meat: 0
 }
```

And I have 2 expressions which have different result one without spread operator

```
Object.keys(ingredients).map(igKey=>{ 
    return [Array(3)]
})
```

and another with spread operator

```
Object.keys(ingredients).map(igKey=>{ 
    return [...Array(3)]
})
```

> Result without spread operator

```
(4) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0: [Array(3)]
1: [Array(3)]
2: [Array(3)]
3: [Array(3)]
```

> Result with spread operator

```
(4) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
1: (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
2: (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
3: (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I read spread operator is used to combine multiple arrays, what operation does spread operator does in this example?

Comment: If you change `[Array(3)]` in your first example to `Array(3)` (no `[ ]`), they'll give the same results. That would in fact be the preferred way to do things, as `[... Array(3)]` creates an array, then creates *another* array and copies the first to the second. Simply `Array(3)` by itself will suffice.

Comment: I would recommend using `Array.from({length: 3})`